# Checkstyle class check

Tags: java, types, equals, checkstyle

I would like to write a Check using Checkstyle that determines if the given class extends some other class AND if there are any usages of '=='.  Can someone help me understand what I need to do ?

Here's what I have so far :

```
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.TokenTypes;

public final class MyEqualsCheck
        extends Check {

    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[] { TokenTypes.EQUAL, TokenTypes.NOT_EQUAL };
    }

    /**
     * Right before we visit the AST, we're allowed to do initialization and setup 
     * here.
     */
    @Override
    public void beginTree(final DetailAST aRootAST) {
    }

    /**
     * Each token that we defined above is visited here.
     */
    @Override
    public void visitToken(final DetailAST ast) {

        final DetailAST lValue = ast.getFirstChild();
        final DetailAST rValue = lValue.getNextSibling();
        //is it possible to determine if lValue and rValue implement a given interface directly or indirectly?
    }

    private DetailAST getLowestParent(final DetailAST aAST) {
        DetailAST lowestParent = aAST;
        while ((lowestParent.getParent() != null)) {
            lowestParent = lowestParent.getParent();
        }
        return lowestParent;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks good as a start. For the ==, look at the class [StringEqualsEqualityCheck](http://ftp.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Code-Analyzer/checkstyle-5.1/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/StringLiteralEqualityCheck.java.htm), which checks for usage of == between two string literals.

For your check, you need to verify that for your class, you don't use a ==. This means that your visitToken will just record whether you've extended another class and whether you use ==.
Then, use finishTree to actually raise the error.

For a detailed example, see [EqualsHashCodeCheck](http://ftp.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Code-Analyzer/checkstyle-5.1/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/EqualsHashCodeCheck.java.htm), which examines a class to see if you have implemented both equals() and hashCode(). Note that it manages multiple classes in the same file correctly, using a map.

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks for your response.  Can you post a snippet of code that illustrates how I can find out if a class implements an interface anywhere in its ancestry?